# Who is Oberon in the Dresden-verse?

Tags: the-dresden-files, mythology

The names Titania and Mab both come to us from Shakespeare, through *A Midsummer Night's Dream* and *Romeo and Juliet*, respectively.  Both are described as queen of the faeries and the consort of Oberon, the king.

This led Orson Scott Card to write an urban fantasy novel (whose name I can't remember at the moment) in which the queen was a major character, and Mab and Titania were two different names for her, and the plot had to do with Oberon doing something problematic.  This is all reasonable enough if you accept Shakespeare as authoritative on this aspect of mythology.

Jim Butcher, on the other hand, took a very different approach: there are two Faerie Courts, each with its own distinct queen.  In the Dresden-verse, Butcher always seems to adhere pretty faithfully to source material for various myths, and find interesting ways to update them and make them seem to work in the modern world.  Which brings us to Mab and Titania, who are both supposed to be the consort of Oberon.

Who is Oberon in the Dresden Files?  I don't believe he's ever actually been mentioned in any of the books, and the obvious answer here--a polygamous situation involving the two queens--is... well... if you've read the books you know there's simply no way that could *possibly* be stable.

Has the author ever said anything about Oberon and his role in-universe?

Answer (score 13):

I think you asking it from the wrong angle: if there would be "Oberon" HE would be a consort to Mab or Titania, akin to Prince Philip to Queen Elisabeth - both queens hold the power tightly and undisputed.

If you are asking for the male counterpart to queens, here is the word of God - [interview with Butcher](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfG2ZIdYdr4&t=6m25s)

According to him, there are in fact two "kings" that represent the opposite character to their queens: Earlking is the summer king - he is Hearne the Hunter that holds the dominion over spirits of the fallen hunters and represents the primal violence and bloodlust, which contrast to rather peaceful Titania. Mab, which can be devious and cruel is a contrasted by the...Santa Claus (or Kringle if you prefer), who is rather<sup>1</sup> kind and generous.

We know very little about the background of both queens: we know that Mab and Titania are sisters and Maeve and Aurora were their biological daughters, but we don't know anything about their fathers. But then, if Maeve's behavior can be any indicator, monogamy is not highly valued virtue in the Faery courts.

I've found also this information (thanks @shamshiel!) that indeed there was a person called Oberon:

> Oberon... well, the guy kind of wound up between Mab and Titania in one of those romantic triangle things, back around Shakespeare's day. He didn't make it. ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/13iexg/hi_im_jim_butcher_im_the_guy_who_takes_credit_for/))

.

> <sup>1</sup>  That is when he is not busy doing other things under his other [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin)

Comment: There is a specific WoJ about Oberon. IIIRC the implication is that he died several centuries ago.

Comment: @Shamshiel thanks, I found it in another interview!

Comment: Prince Philip is Queen Elizabeth's consort. Prince Charles is her son.

Comment: /facepalm... I'll correct that.